# Gensim Import Error "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Tags: python, winapi, dll, pycharm, gensim

Basically I have installed Gensim 3.7.3 from Python 3.7.1  , but while importing it in Pycharm i got an error: 
"ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

I want to use Word2Vec model of Gensim but due to this error, I am stuck. I can't Change Python Version too.

Need Help! how I get Gensim Imported in this version of Python using Pycharm

import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

Comment: Does the import work outside of PyCharm?

Comment: It almost always means you are trying to load a 64 bit DLL in a 32 bit process, or vice versa

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah i know that , i want any solution of this issue.

Comment: If you have a 32 bit process, load the 32 bit version of the dll. If you have a 64 bit process, load the 64 bit version of the dll.

Comment: @James thanks for asking this question. Actually this solved my problem. I imported it outside PyCharm and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so my problem resolved when i tried to import gensim outside Pycharm. 
I Imported directly in python console and it worked. 
Thanks @James.